# Expectation with subscript

Tags: expected-value, notation

I have a question. A and B are normal distibutions. 
how to calculate $\operatorname{E}_{A,B}[A^2]$ does it scene that I drop the B in the statement or do I have to consider the B somehow ?

Comment: Try expressing the expectation as an integral over $A$ and $B$. That should get you started.

Comment: is it true that $\operatorname{E}_{A,B}[A^2] =  \operatorname{E}[A^2| A,B] $?

Comment: No, that is not true. $E_{A,B}[A^2]$ denotes the expectation of $A^2$ with respect to $A$ and $B$ whereas $E[A^2|A,B]$ denotes the expectation of $A^2$ given $A$ and $B$--which is not very useful in this context.

Comment: yes, well this is what confuses me. this with respect to, i dont really know what this means and how to express this. conditional expectation, I can google and read further

Comment: $E_{A,B}[A^2]= \int_A \int_B p(A|x)p(B|x)x^2 $ does this make scene ?

Comment: No, I'm afraid it doesn't. What is $x$?

Comment: i was thinking about this
when $E[X]= \int_x x f(x) dx$ ok, when i then want to know $E_B[A]$
wouldnt this be $=\int_B A(B) B$ ?? so when both are normal is this than the sum over all the values of the B normal distribution, where it is not zero and then times the value of the A distribution at this point and sum them all up. does this makes scene would this be the convolution of two normals ??? but what when i also have $E_{A,B}$ does this make scene. and for $E_B[A^2] = \int_B A B^2 $ so the probability of of b is squared

Comment: and if there is N(A| B, $\sigma$) and N(B|$\mu$,s) when i ask for $E_{A,B}[A]$ who would it look like ? $\int_B A(B)*B $ would it become zero ?

Comment: is it the xpectation of the joint normal ? please tell me :(

Comment: I suggest you have a look at an introductory book to probability. Some are available for free online. For example, https://www.dartmouth.edu/~chance/teaching_aids/books_articles/probability_book/amsbook.mac.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subscript just means that the expectation is with respect to the joint distribution of $(A,B)$.  Use of the subscript does not add anything in this case, since there is nothing in the expectation that depends on the random variable $B$.  In this case you have:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
\mathbb{E}_{A,B}(A^2) 
&= \int \int a^2 p(a,b) da \text{ } db \\[6pt]
&= \int \int a^2 p(a) p(b|a) da \text{ } db \\[6pt]
&= \int a^2 p(a) \Big( \int  p(b|a) db \Big) da \\[6pt]
&= \int a^2 p(a) da  \\[6pt]
&= \mathbb{E}_A(A^2). \\[6pt]
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

In this kind of case you really don't need any subscript on the expectation operator.  In the absence of a subscript we just assume that the expectation is taken over the joint distribution of all random variables in the expression.

Comment: In step 3, how do you move the integral over b all the way inside? I believe you swap the order of integration, but I'm not 100% convinced about the validity of doing that

Comment: Yes, it is interchange of the order of integration.  In this case it would be fine, since the integrand is continuous (infinitely differentiable), and vanishing at both ends.